# Android layout: center view on another non-sibling view using layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to centre a View on the centre of another View in another Layout, as per this [sketch of layout relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddhwv.png) with the following constrains (or lack of):

- The total width of the layout (`?'`) is unknown at compile time (depends on other stuff around it)
- The width of the green boxes (`?`) is also unknown (being a function of the total width)
- The width of the narrow and wide boxes in the first and second row shall be the same
- The width of the red boxes (`w`) is known and fixed
- The red boxes in the third row shall be centred each on the centre of the corresponding green box.

I know how to achieve this through code, but I prefer to implement those constrains in the layout file; so far I could implement all of them excepted the last one.

I have tried with 3 `LinearLayout`s one below the other, but I did not find a way to relate the horizontal position of a `View` in a `Layout` with a `View` in different `Layout`.

I did not even tried with `TableLayout`, as cells cannot span multiple columns.

I am missing something obvious? Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing this using code or via layout?

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel thank for your reply. Sorry, I thought the requirement for using layout rather than code was explicit enough; I am not a native English speaker and I may be not familiar with English rhetoric devices. I have emphasized this requirement and moved it to a more prominent place.